# Custom block update rendering when reused

Tags: javascript, block-editor

First question here! I'm an experienced WP developer, but pretty new to React so my vocabulary might be a little off... I developed a custom (Gutenberg) block that have to update is content on almost every block manipulation on the block editor.

It works great, mostly: i "listen" to changes with a wp.data.subscribe function and update the block attributes with `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlockAttributes`.

The problem is that the blocks stop updating when converted to a reusable block or put in one (like a reusable group). It's fine in the reusable block manager, but the feature that let you edit a reusable block inside the post it is used on is like a frame that don't fire my wp.data.subscribe function.

How do i check for modifications in this "window" and update blocks inside it?

It's just a backend problem. The client side rendering is dynamic so it works fine.

Thank you,

Nicolas

Here is the code related to my block :

```
//Process step bloc. The step number is added and refreshed automaticaly after any change to any blocs
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText } = wp.editor;
registerBlockType( 'blocs-aide-brio/bloc-etape', {
    title: 'Étape de procédure',
    icon: 'editor-ol',
    category: 'aide-brio',
    attributes: {
      etape: {
        type: 'number',
        default: 1,
      },
      content: {
          type: 'array',
          source: 'children',
          selector: 'p',
      },
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const { attributes: { content, etape }, setAttributes } = props;
        const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };
        return (
          <div>
            <div class="etape-numero">
              <span>{ etape }.</span>
            </div>
            <RichText
              tagName="p"
              onChange={ onChangeContent }
              value={ content }
            />
          </div>
        );
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
      return <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ props.attributes.content } />;
    },
} );

//Steps reordering after content change
wp.data.subscribe( function() {
  var blocs = wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlocks(); //Create an array of the current posts blocs
  var numero = 0;
  for ( const bloc of blocs ) { //Loop in the blocs array
    for ( const sousBloc of bloc.innerBlocks ) { //Loop in the innerblocs
      if ( sousBloc.name === 'blocs-aide-brio/bloc-etape' ) { //If the bloc is a step
        numero += 1;
        wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlockAttributes( sousBloc.clientId, { etape: numero } ); //Update the step number
      } else if ( sousBloc.name === 'core/heading' && sousBloc.attributes.level === 2 ) { //Restart the step numbers every h2
        numero = 0;
      }
    }
    if ( bloc.name === 'blocs-aide-brio/bloc-etape' ) { //If the bloc is a step
      numero += 1;
      wp.data.dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).updateBlockAttributes( bloc.clientId, { etape: numero } ); //Update the step number
    } else if ( bloc.name === 'core/heading' && bloc.attributes.level === 2 ) { //Restart the step numbers every h2
      numero = 0;
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: Can you share the block code? The way you're updating your block attributes sounds like what you are supposed to use if you're updating someone else's block, rather than how you would normally update your own block's attributes.

Comment: It's because i need any block (core, custom or from an other plugin) addition, deletion, reordering or transformation to update all the pages custom blocks. The problem is only when the custom blocks are flagged as reusable. I will edit my question with the code, but i need to translate the comments first...

Comment: If it can help someone having the same problem in the future, it's a bug and at the moment, there is no solution. You can follow the ticket here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16614.

Here's Riad Benguella's (lead Block editor developper) answer: yes, I don't see how this problem could be solved because the reusable blocks work on a separate data module registry. I believe ideally the inline-editing for reusable blocks should be refactored or removed in favor of links to the edit page of reusable blocks potentially.